# Swift compiler crashes when two protocols reference each other

Tags: compiler-errors, swift, protocols

In swift, this code crashes the compiler:

```
protocol Foo {
    var delegate : FooDelegate { get set }
}
protocol FooDelegate {
    func something(foo : Foo)
}
```

I need to use this pattern, because there are multiple implementations of Foo, and each of them uses the same delegate protocol.

Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Comment: At worst, use `func something(foo : AnyObject)` or `func something(foo : Any)`.

Comment: Does Foo have to be a protocol?

Comment: Crashes for me, too, on beta 3. File a radar. Also, note that delegate protocols should always be annotated `@class_protocol` or `@objc` to ensure that only classes can implement them.